# Why does this use of \textwidth cause pdflatex to crash (not exit!)?

Tags: tables, errors, pdftex, debugging

I ran into this problem when playing around with tables.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h!]
  400 MHz \qquad 800MHz
\centering
\showthe\numexpr\textwidth\relax
\tracingall
\begin{tabular}{|0.4*\textwidth||p{0.9cm}p{0.9cm}p{0.9cm}p{0.9cm}||p{0.9cm}p{0.9cm}p{0.9cm}p{1cm}|}
\hline No. of Cells & Acc. Voltage [MV] & No. of Cavities & Cavity Length [cm] & Total Length of Cavities [m] & Acc. Voltage [MV] & No. of Cavities & Cavity Length [cm] & Total Length of Cavities\\ \hline
1& 4.63&2591&112.42&2913 &4.83&2484&56.21&1397 \\ \hline
2& 8.30&1446&149.90&2168 &8.45&1420&74.94&1064 \\ \hline
3& 12.45&964&187.37&1806 &12.67&947&93.69&887 \\ \hline
4& 16.61&723&224.84&1626 &16.91&710&112.42&798 \\ \hline
5& 20.76&578&262.34&1516 &21.13&568&131.16&745 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Demonstrating how the total length of RF cavities in the lattice depends on both the number of cells per cavity and on the frequency of the cavity.}
\label{tab:comparingrf}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Use of 0.4*\textwidth here causes pdflatex to take up 100% cpu and never exit.  My laptop currently sounds like it is about to take off.  Have I done something absolutely forbidden here that I was not aware of?  I would have thought though that ideally nothing was so forbidden that it crashed the compiler rather than tell me I have done something wrong.

Comment: In any programming language that has counters and if statements it is impossible to automatically detect that the user has  programmed an infinite (or in this case very large) loop.

Comment: Note that you don't need the `*` when multiplying a register by some value. Use `0.4\textwidth`.

Comment: Where is that `tex capacity exceeded` error message in the only case in which it would really have been appropriate?

Comment: (old question) I guess either the capacity in this case is very large that it takes a long time to reach the capacity, or the execution is so slow that the capacity is only reached after a long time. (compare: `while(true) {}` in C doesn't consume any memory either)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Werner has shown the correct syntax, but to explain what happens with your document.

Note that `*\textwidth|` is the same as `*{\number\textwidth}{|}` and denotes multiple `|` so it causes latex to go into a loop with a counter set to `\textwidth` (viewed as a number by taking the value in `sp` which is 22609920 at the default `article` text width) and then repeatedly redefining the macro that holds the array preamble in a loop adding one more `|` each time.

If you turn on tracing and stop it after a bit you see

```
\@iwhilenum #1->\ifnum #1\expandafter \@iwhilenum \else \expandafter \@gobble \
fi {#1}
#1<-\@tempcnta >\z@ \relax \edef \reserved@a {\reserved@a |}\advance \@tempcnta
 \m@ne \relax 
{\ifnum: (level 3) entered on line 8}
{true}
{\relax}
{\edef}

\reserved@a ->|0.4|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
! Interruption.
```

Probably if you don't stop it you eventually run out of input buffer or some such, I didn't wait to find out.

Answer (score 9):

You need to specify the column type, which you forgot to do. For example, use `p{0.4\textwidth}`.